# Editing Woocommerce get_price_html() format

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is a price.php file to show the price of products at category level in Woocommerce. It produces the following output:

> ₹1,504 Save 66% per Bundle

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>   
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to edit the format but I am not able to do that I want to use ₹1,504  to manipulate it. How to get this?

Comment: already the option available in the admin section to change price format did you try that.

Comment: not price format i want to use the price ₹1,504 @RaviShankar

Comment: you can customize by using "woocommerce_price_html" filter hooks, see the example code below, it's easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) in Codex for more info on adding filters to [apply_filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) calls.

From `get_price_html` in `class-wc-product`:

```
return apply_filters('woocommerce_get_price_html', $price, $this);
```

So to add your own filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ){
    return 'Was:' . str_replace( '<ins>', ' Now:<ins>', $price );
}
```

For more information please check this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83367/how-to-edit-the-get-price-html-on-woocommerce).

Would you please add above code in your `functions.php`?

Comment: return apply_filters('woocommerce_get_price_html', $price, $this); where to add this? @purvik7373

Comment: You don't have to enter `return apply_filters('woocommerce_get_price_html', $price, $this);`. It's just for your understanding.

Comment: You only have to enter `add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ){
    return 'Was:' . str_replace( '<ins>', ' Now:<ins>', $price );
}` In your active theme `functions.php` file.

Comment: when i add your code in functions.php it changes my ₹1,504 Save 66% per Bundle but i dont want to change that i want to just extract $price from it and manipulate it @purvik7373

Answer (score 0):

You can also change by using filter hooks see the below example code.

```
function cs_custom_simple_product_price_html( $price ) {
  global $product;
  $parcels = 10; // Edit the number of parcels here!
  $parcel_price = $product->get_price() / 10;
  $html = '<span class="parcels">' . $parcels . 'x </span>';
  $html .= woocommerce_price( $parcel_price ) . '<br />';
  $html .= '<span class="without-interest">' . __( 'sem juros' ) . '</span><br />';
  $html .= woocommerce_price( $product->get_price() );
  return $html;
  }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_html', 'cs_custom_simple_product_price_html' );
```

Comment: under the current active theme function.php file